# Swift append String var to an List by reference

Tags: swift, reference, append

Hi i want to append string by reference to a List.
for example :

```
var str = "old"
func foo(){
  list.append(str)
}
func changeStr(){
  str = "new"
}
```

my problem is that the value of str ("old") is being appended and not the reference, so when i change str to "new" it doesn't take any effect on the list.
my question is how i can append reference to a string var?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the string in a class. Have the array hold members of your class, and update the class object with a new string value.

Just like if you had an array of ints in whatever language you are used to.

Best solution is to get used to standard Swift/functional idioms.

-- EXAMPLE --

```
    class StringObject {
        init(str: String) {
            self.str = str
        }
        var str: String = ""
    }

    let so = StringObject(str: "old")
    func foo() {
        list.append(so)
    }
    func changeStr() {
        so.str = "new"
    }
```

Comment: can you please provid an example?